# How to make conda or mamba verbose using environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, conda, mamba

I am looking for an environment variable I can set to make mamba verbose while it is resolving the dependency to see if it is stuck at a certain stage.

Comment: No environment variable does this, and in general environment variables are not a good way to pass arguments to `conda`. You may have no options besides `-vv`

Comment: @MattThompson I'd say this is an answer

Comment: okay, I'll copy as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done either through Conda configuration (i.e., `.condarc`) or an environment variable. The environment variable has the highest priority, so I recommend setting default behavior via the configuration such that the environment variable is still available for overriding.

There is an (older) article detailing the Conda configuration system: [*"The Conda Configuration Engine for Power Users"*](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-configuration-engine-power-users).

#### Conda Configuration

The configuration variable is **verbosity**. Here is the description:

```bash
$ conda config --describe verbosity
# # verbosity (int)
# #   aliases: verbose
# #   Sets output log level. 0 is warn. 1 is info. 2 is debug. 3 is trace.
# # 
# verbosity: 0
```

which shows `0` is the default. It can be set with

```bash
conda config --set verbosity 2  # debug by default
```

#### Environment Variable

All Conda configuration variables can be set via `CONDA_*` environment variables. To override the **verbosity** configuration, one can use:

```bash
## temporary setting
CONDA_VERBOSITY=2 conda info

## permanent setting, e.g., in a .bashrc or .bash_profile
export CONDA_VERBOSITY=2
```