# How to install Python package eelbrain on macOS

Tags: python, macos, installation, conda-forge

I would like to run a TRF analysis in Python using the "eelbrain" package. I tried installing it in a new Anaconda Python environment and basically tried all possible ways of installing eelbrain (using the Terminal or the Anaconda Navigator GUI as described [in the GitHub documentation](https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/wiki/Installing)), but none of it worked. The "solving package specifications" process just runs on and on until I end it. Ideally, I would like to use eelbrain in [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29).

I saw [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eelbrain) that there seem to be files for macOS on [Conda Forge](https://twitter.com/condaforge), but [on eelbrain's GitHub page](https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/tree/main) it says that macOS is no longer available on Conda Forge (if you look at the badges at the end of the README). My colleague was able to install eelbrain on his Windows PC, so I guess there's really a problem with macOS.

So long story short, my question is: **Is it possible to install eelbrain on macOS—maybe without using Conda Forge—and if yes, how?**

I have two devices I could use (one old iMac and a newer Macbook), here are the specs:

Device 1: iMac (mid 2015) with macOS Big Sur v.11.7.10, Anaconda Navigator 2.5.2, Spyder v.5.4.3 with Python 3.9.18

Device 2: Macbook Air M2 (2022) with macOS Sonoma v.14.2.1, Anaconda Navigator v.2.5.2, Spyder v.5.4.3 with Python 3.11.5

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could try running your eelbrain command with the `--debug-warnings` and `--show-warnings` flags, and see if that outputs any additional info that can help pinpoint what is going on.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do this, usually I would run this code in the terminal: conda create -n eelbrain -c conda-forge eelbrain
Now I just added one of the flags: 
conda create -n eelbrain -c conda-forge eelbrain --show-warnings
But when I run it, I get this error, so I think I made a mistake with the flag:
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: unrecognized arguments: --debug-warnings

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking this was the eelbrain command that was getting stuck. You can make conda more verbose by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71036071/how-to-make-conda-or-mamba-verbose-using-environment-variable

Comment: You could also try doing a [pip install](https://pypi.org/project/eelbrain/) instead of using conda `pip install eelbrain`

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help! I also tried just pip installing it, but it throws an error telling me that it could not build wheels for eelbrain.

Comment: There is a way to manually install wheels using an already built wheel. There's a wheel for eelbrain on [https://pypi.org/project/eelbrain/#files](https://pypi.org/project/eelbrain/#files). The only wheel listed is for MacOs! Hopefully it's for the same version of MacOs that you are using. After downloading the wheel, you can install it by `cd`ing to your downloads directory and running `pip install eelbrain-0.39.10-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl`

Comment: In the README on https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/wiki/Installing#a-branch-from-github it says with respect to a pip installation on MACOS "NOTE: In order for this to work on macOS, the *Xcode Command Line Tools* need to be installed. If they are not, the pip install command will fail with a long error message including fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the eelbrain documentation contains the information on how to install it from GitHub: *[Installing [Eelbrain]. A branch from GitHub](https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/wiki/Installing#a-branch-from-github)*

The relevant content:

```
Download the environment file and create the eeldev conda environment:

$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/master/env-dev.yml
$ conda env create --file=env-dev.yml

Activate the environment:

$ conda activate eeldev

Install the relevant development branch into the environment. If installing a specific branch, replace "master" with the branch name:

$ pip install https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/archive/master.zip

    NOTE: In order for this to work on macOS, the Xcode Command Line Tools need to be installed. If they are not, the pip install command will fail with a long error message including fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found. In order to install the Command Line Tools, run:

    $ xcode-select --install
```

I assume `xcode-select --install` should be done first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried this, but it didn
t work either. I made sure xcode is installed, but if I run the command to create an environment with the .yml file, I get the error message "Solving environment: failed".

Comment: The `https://github.com/christianbrodbeck/Eelbrain/blob/main/env-dev.yml`  has around 50 dependencies. First I would try to use `mamba` instead of `conda` and add `-vvv` for debug.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it on a [MacBook Pro M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#14-inch_and_16-inch_(2021%E2%80%93present)) today (Anaconda 2.5.2 with Spyder 5.4.3 and Python 3.11.5) and pip installing eelbrain worked there without any of the problems I had on the other devices.

When I tried to import eelbrain in Spyder, I got some error messages because there were dependencies missing (nibabel, wx AKA [wxPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython), colormath, and pymatreader), but I also pip installed them and now it seems to work. At least I can import eelbrain and load a test dataset.

I hope this works now, but I still don't understand why it didn't work on my other devices.